# execvp behaves weirdly with ls

Tags: c, execvp

Here is a minimal reproducible example of my issue

```c
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *a[] = {"ls", "-l", "~", "..", "-A", NULL};
  execvp(a[0], a);
  return 0;
}
```

I expected this to work as it would when I run `ls -l ~ .. -A` in the shell, but on running the executable after compiling I get the following output

```
❯ clang main.c -o a
❯ ./a
ls: -A: No such file or directory
ls: ~: No such file or directory
..:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 me  staff  96 Sep  1 11:56 test
```

Comment: And what *is* the "issue"? What happens when you build the code? What happens when you run it? What *should* happen? Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And what happens when you run `ls -l \~ .. -A` from the shell? What does this tell you about execvp?

Comment: The tilde problem is easy to explain: It's expanded by the *shell* not by the operating system or the `exec*` family of functions.

Comment: @Jens on running `ls -l ~ .. -A` from the shell, it lists all files and directories in home and parent directory including `.`files and relevant information such as time and permissions

Comment: @mTvare You did not run the command I proposed. The tilde must be quoted, since the shell expands it, while execvp does not.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `execvp(a[0], &a[1]);`?

Comment: @Lundin No, that skips `argv[0]` (or rather it puts `-l` in `argv[0]`).

Comment: @Jens now both shell and execvp do the same, but even on changing ~ to actual home path in code, it says `ls: -A: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try putting `-A` after `-l`

Comment: @user3386109 it seems to work now, but isn't `ls` supposed to parse -A wherever it is ?

Comment: Some commands do take options after filenames, but some stop parsing options as soon as they find anything that isn't an option.

Comment: @user3386109 The problem here is that `ls` behaves differently when running from a shell (where `-A` is okay to have anywhere) and when called from `exec*` (where putting `-A` anywhere doesn't work).

Comment: @mTvare I think the question should be rewritten to be about *why* there's a difference in behavior between `ls` in the shell and `ls` from `exec*` (in regards to the `-A` option). Perhaps posted as a new question, and this one deleted, to start from a clean slate.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude user3386109 already made it clear, so do I clear a new post?

Comment: `'~'` in Linux shell is a shorthand for `/home/youruser/` The expansion happens in the shell itself and is called *tilde expansion*. C knows nothing of shell internals any more than shell knows of C internals. You improperly use `'~'` where you should use `"/home/youruser"`.. Then you will get a listing of your home directory, and then directory immediately above the current working directory with `".."` (the choices seem odd, but there is nothing wrong with them)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That depends on the implementation of `ls` that you're using. On my machine, typing `ls *.txt -A` in the shell results in the error message that the OP posted.